# Solve non-homogenous PDE using Fourier transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Given PDE:

$$u_t=u_{xx}-\gamma u+g(x), -\infty \lt x \lt \infty, t \gt0, \gamma \gt 0$$ with $$u(x,0)=0, g(x)=xe^{-x^2/2}.$$

Use Fourier transform to find the solution of the given PDE.

**My Approach **

I took the Fourier transform and got the corresponding equation $$U_t(k,t)=-k^2U(k,t)-\gamma U(k,t)-ik \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k^2/2}$$

My question is how to revert back into the original space using the inverse Fourier transformation.

Comment: You made a mistake for the fourier transform of $g(x)$ you should have a derivative.

Comment: What do you mean by a derivative?

Comment: The Fourier transform of $xh(x)$ is $i\frac {d}{dk}H(k)$ where $H(k)$ is the transform fourier of $e^{-x^2/2}$

Comment: Thanks for identifying my mistake. Is it okay now?

Comment: YW  Thats what I got indeed but with $\sqrt {2\pi}$

Comment: Yeah you’re right. Can you help me to get the solution in actual space.

Comment: You need to solve the differential equation

Comment: With theis correction you will get an easier answer. Find the integrating factor and solve the DE with respect to time $t$

Comment: I did but I am not able to get.

Comment: Can you post what you get we will check it toegether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After correcting the mistake of the Fourier Transform of $g(x)$, I got this:
$$U_t(k,t)=-k^2U(k,t)-\gamma U(k,t)-ik \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k^2/2}$$
$$U_t(k,t)+(k^2+\gamma) U(k,t)=-ik \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k^2/2}$$
Solving the DE with Integrating Factor:
$$(U(k,t)e^{(k^2+\gamma)t} )'=-ik \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k^2/2}e^{(k^2+\gamma)t} $$
Integrate:
$$U(k,t)e^{(k^2+\gamma)t} =-ik \sqrt{2\pi}e^{-k^2/2}\int e^{(k^2+\gamma)t}dt +C(k)$$
$$U(k,t)e^{(k^2+\gamma)t} =-ik \frac {\sqrt{2\pi}}{(k^2+\gamma)}e^{-k^2/2} e^{(k^2+\gamma)t} +C(k)$$
$$U(k,t) =-ik \frac {\sqrt{2\pi}}{(k^2+\gamma)}e^{-k^2/2} +C(k)e^{-(k^2+\gamma)t}$$
$$U(k,0)=0 \implies C(k) =ik \frac {\sqrt{2\pi}}{(k^2+\gamma)}e^{-k^2/2}$$
$$U(k,t) =-ik \frac {\sqrt{2\pi}}{(k^2+\gamma)}e^{-k^2/2}(1 -e^{-(k^2+\gamma)t})$$

---

Edit:

You have the condition that should simplify a little the equation:
$$U(k,0)=0$$
Note that you have this result:
$$\mathcal{F^{-1}}\{ikF(k)\}=f'(x)$$
And you also have:
$$\mathcal{F^{-1}} \{\frac {2a}{a^2+k^2}\}=e^{-a|x|}$$

Comment: Yes, I got the same thing.

Comment: Where $c(k)$ is any function of $k$ @AtulAnuragSharma

Comment: Yeah, I got the answer up-to this part. Also, $c(k)$ can be found using the initial conditon.

Comment: That's good @AtulAnuragSharma

Comment: The trouble I am facing is in get the inverse Fourier.

Comment: You need to apply the initial condition @AtulAnuragSharma it will simplify the equation

Comment: you have that $$U(k,0)=0$$ @AtulAnuragSharma  It makes things easier

Comment: What's the final answer, can you post it too?

Comment: You are close to  the final answer. You only need the convolution formula because you have a product of two functions. @AtulAnuragSharma